# how can i search a word before a ( whithout selecting the ( with regex

Tags: regex

Imagine the case of a text like  :

```
Abc:  
deF:(  
gH:  
iLm:(
```

i want to select only "deF:" and "iLm:": can i do it whit *regex* ?
something like ***\w+:\(+** -last

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What implementation?

You want positive lookahead:

```
\w+:(?=\()
```

Note that the `(` is escaped in the lookahead expression.  You may need an additional `\` to embed the expression itself as a string literal in your language (whatever that is).

Comment: thanks! you did indeed answered the question even if encountered another problem. but i'm trying to figure out myself how to find CoffeScript Methods in a document

Comment: \w+(?=:\((.*=>|.*->)) this does work in Sublime Text 2 but not in Pygments on the same text pygments also selects "stage3Dx:(@eventToPoint(event).x / @canvas.width()) * 2 - 1" while ST2 doesn't. why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with those implementations, but the documentation should explain.  By the way, you should be able to condense `\w+(?=:((.*=>|.*->))` into `\w+(?=:(.*[=-]>))` with a "standard" regex engine (may affect your match group number, though).

Comment: as you thought the condensed version worked worse now all \w: are selected as far as i can notice i'll keep playing with \w+(?=:((.*=>|.*->)) so that aaa:(`.*`)-> sss:-> www:=> qqq:(`.*`)=> are good and aaa:(`.*`)-5 is not

Answer (score 0):

or simply to a readline of the file, find the occurence of ":(" in the file.
if its there, keep the word from the line, else move to next line.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that:

```
(\w+:)\(
```

Depends on your language, `(\w+)` gives you `iLm:`